# Рамка в стиле CATerpillar

Tags: css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Какими средствами лучше всего сделать рамку, скажем к форме комментариев, как на присутствующем здесь изображении? 
Я понимаю что ее можно задать в бэкграунде, но пишу сюда потому как не исключаю что далеко не все знаю о возможностях таких свойств как border и outline. К тому же хотелось бы избежать лишних загрузок изображений на странице.

Comment: Напишите, что это за рамка, какие средства уже попробовали и что вас в них не устраивает. Без этого непонятно, что вам нужно и в чём у вас загвоздка.

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел что-то в этом роде

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.gradient {
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: 10 repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFCC00, #FFCC00 10px, #000000 10px, #000000 20px, #FFCC00 20px, #FFCC00 30px, #000000 30px, #000000 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwdrye

Картинку заменишь на свою

```css
div { margin: 20px;   border-origin: content-box; float:left;}
.stamp {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 9px transparent;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4IV0.jpg)  9 / 9px / 12px round;
   -moz-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4IV0.jpg) 9 / 9px round;
   -o-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4IV0.jpg) 9  round;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4IV0.jpg) round 9 / 9px / 12px;
  width: 158px; height: 88px; float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="stamp"></div>
```

```
<div class="stamp"></div>
```

Вариант без картинок

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GExXEK

```css
div { margin: 20px;   border-origin: content-box; float:left;}
.stamp {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 9px transparent;
  border-image: 10 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFCC00, #FFCC00 10px, 
    #000000 10px, #000000 20px, #FFCC00 20px, #FFCC00 30px, #000000 30px, 
    #000000 40px);
  width: 158px; height: 88px; float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="stamp"></div>
```

Comment: По моему излишне мудрено. Если дело дошло все-таки до загрузок картинок, проще наверное форму вложить в див с заданным фоном